# Why the behavior for declaring vs does not declare the variable in JavaScript for Loop is different?

Tags: javascript, python, recursion

edit: changed the title to more relevant question.

I found there is a **bug** with the JavaScript. If you set the variable without the variable declaration `let` or `var`. For example `for (n=1;n<10;n++)` vs with variable declaration `for (let n=1;n<10;n++)`. You can call `n` variable outside the function but it violates the for-loop condition `n<10`. The output is `15`

JavaScript for Loop without the variable declaration. `for (n=1;n<10;n++)`

```js
grid = [
  [5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
  [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
  [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
  [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
  [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]
];

function possible(r, c, n) {
  /// check the row
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    if (grid[r][i] == n) return false;
  /// check the column
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    if (grid[i][c] == n) return false;
  /// check the 3x3 grid
  r0 = Math.floor(r / 3) * 3;
  c0 = Math.floor(c / 3) * 3;
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      if (grid[r0 + i][c0 + j] == n) return false;
    }
  }
  /// all check passed
  return true;
}

function solve() {
  for (let r = 0; r < 9; r++) {
    for (let c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
      /// check grid with value of 0
      if (grid[r][c] === 0) {
        /// check for possible solution
        for (n = 1; n < 10; n++) {
          if (possible(r, c, n)) {
            /// there is a possibility of the selected solution is a bad one.
            /// to solve this, use backtracking: try -> if it turns out the solution is a bad one, we go back to 0.
            grid[r][c] = n;
            /// recursion
            solve();
            grid[r][c] = 0;
          }
        }
        /// if there is no solution, we have to return.
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(grid);
  prompt("More?")
}

solve();

console.log(n)
```

JavaScript for Loop with variable declaration `for (let n=1;n<10;n++)`

```js
grid = [
  [5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
  [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
  [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
  [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
  [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]
];

function possible(r, c, n) {
  /// check the row
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    if (grid[r][i] == n) return false;
  /// check the column
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    if (grid[i][c] == n) return false;
  /// check the 3x3 grid
  r0 = Math.floor(r / 3) * 3;
  c0 = Math.floor(c / 3) * 3;
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      if (grid[r0 + i][c0 + j] == n) return false;
    }
  }
  /// all check passed
  return true;
}

function solve() {
  for (let r = 0; r < 9; r++) {
    for (let c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
      /// check grid with value of 0
      if (grid[r][c] === 0) {
        /// check for possible solution
        for (let n = 1; n < 10; n++) {
          if (possible(r, c, n)) {
            /// there is a possibility of the selected solution is a bad one.
            /// to solve this, use backtracking: try -> if it turns out the solution is a bad one, we go back to 0.
            grid[r][c] = n;
            /// recursion
            solve();
            grid[r][c] = 0;
          }
        }
        /// if there is no solution, we have to return.
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(grid);
  prompt("More?")
}

solve();

console.log(n)
```

Comment: You need to declare **all** your variables in JavaScript, **particularly** in recursive code.

Comment: In Javascript, `let` (and `const`) respects scope constraints while `var` does not, meaning (in a very basic nutshell) any variable declared with `var` exists everywhere and can be accessed and mutated from anywhere (which is a very common source of bugs). In general, never use `var` unless you have a very good reason for it.

Comment: `let` and `var` differ in their scoping abilities, which is why it isn't satisfying your `n < 10` condition

Comment: Well `var` is still scoped to the enclosing function, but yes that's certainly a salient difference. In the case of this particular code however, I'm not sure how that would cause a problem.

Comment: Since Python variables are function scoped, they're analogous to `var` in JS. So I don't see why the JS code using `var` would fail.

Comment: Please post the code with the problem, not the code that works.

Comment: **declare the variable using `var` instead of `let`** -- which variable are you talking about? Please edit the code to show what you're talking about. Also, what is the expected result versus what you're actually getting?

Comment: @Barmar I have removed the Python code to not complicate the discussion. Please kindly check the difference between the 2 snippet code.

Comment: I completely misunderstood the question. I thought you were talking about the difference between `let` and `var`. But it's actually about whether you declare the variable or not declare the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it a bit more explicit, inside the `solve` function in the two snippets, nested inside two `for`-loops and an `if`-statement, we have either of these blocks -- the only difference is that the first one does not declare the variable `n` and the second one does:

```js
        for (n = 1; n < 10; n++) {
          if (possible(r, c, n)) {
            grid[r][c] = n;
            solve();
            grid[r][c] = 0;
          }
        }
```

```js
        for (let n = 1; n < 10; n++) {
          if (possible(r, c, n)) {
            grid[r][c] = n;
            solve();
            grid[r][c] = 0;
          }
        }
```

There is no problem here in the difference between `let` and `var`.  The second one would still work if you used `var`, although you'd have to be careful about not reusing it in the function without re-initializing it -- not an issue with `let`, where the variable is scoped only to the `for`-loop where it's declared.

But there is a serious difference in JS between a declared variable and an undeclared one.  A declared variable is restricted to the scope where it's defined; `let` and `const` are local to the containing block, and `var` to the containing function. An undeclared variable is global across your entire program; if anything changes `n` anywhere, it's changed for your function.

So, if we examine the correct second sample first, we declare `n` as local to the `for`-loop, try out the possibility of `n` being `1`, and, say, find it's not possible, so move on to `2`, which is also not possible, but when we try `3`, we find that it is possible.  (I'm not using your sample grid, just making things up here; the idea should be the same regardless of your data.)  So now we recursively call `solve` and reach this loop again.  We create *another* scoped variable  `n`, do our work with it  We finish that call and return to this loop, with our *initial* `n` in scope, and on the next iteration, set it to `4`.  And we proceed on our merry way.  (There looks to be other work to do here to make this a complete Sudoku solver; at a quick analysis, you always backtrack and never actually report the solved grid; but that's not germane to the discussion of variable declaration/scoping.)

Now we try your first sample.  We don't declare `n`, so it's set as a global variable.  We try out the possibility of `n` being `1` and `2`, which aren't possible.  We try `3`, which is possible, so we recursively call `solve` and reach this loop again.  We initialize `n` to 1, and go through all the possibilities, ending with `n` past the end of the loop, meaning `n` is 10.  We return from the recursive call back to our first loop, hitting the line `grid[r][c] = 0`, and then we hit the increment step of our `for` loop, `n++`, and we set the (global, remember) value of `n` to `11`.  Since `n < 10` is `false`, we are done with our loop, and with the function.

When you log `n`, you will now get `11`, having skipped most of the possibilities along the way.  (In your data, you get `15`, which means you'd come out of more levels of recursion before quitting; again, I'm inventing the data to show the idea of the problem, not the details of your data.)

The lesson should be simple: always declare your variables.  These days, there is no real reason to use `var`.  My recommendation would be to use `const` as often as you can, and use `let` when you can't.  But that's not the important part.  The important part is simply to never use an undeclared variable.